# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

Tags: django

Django Version: 3.1.5

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnbk2.png)

So, I'm studying Django. When I try to generate random data for my project I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProjects\DJANGO\myblogsite\blog\management\commands\create_data.py", line 2, in <module>
    from core.models import Category, Post, Comment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

create_data.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from core.models import Category, Post, Comment
from random import randint
import datetime
```

Has anybody a clue how to deal with this problem?

Comment: `from blog.models import Category, Post, Comment`

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from blog.models import Category, Post, Comment
from random import randint
import datetime
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blog'"

Comment: Does myblogsite.blog.models work for you? Is there any other folder outside the myblogsite folder?

Comment: It also doesn't work. ---- ''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProjects\DJANGO\myblogsite\blog\management\commands\create_data.py", line 2, in <module>
    from myblogsite.blog.models import Category, Post, Comment
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myblogsite''' ---- Just folder named "DJANGO", but it only contains "myblogsite" folder. Maybe I should have put "create_data.py" file in diffrent dir? But where?

Comment: Try moving the python file two directories up and try the import statements that I mentioned. Also in the present configuration, try `import ../../models`. I think this relative addressing should work.